# How Can i copy a mysql record and save with different id using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, copy, crud

I am new in PHP. I have an idea. Can i copy a recoed of table and save it with different id in same table?

For example i have a web form with different fields. I use that form to store data in database. Now i have a page where i display that record and use CRUD operations. When user click on Edit Button it goes on Form where he see a Button of Create copy. When user click on Create Copy button it just begin to start making a copy of selected data and store same data with different id?

[image: create copy]

Comment: as long as you don't use a unique combo kind of key this is possible. Why think just make a replica of the DB and try doing it once. This should work unless you have no combination unique key

Comment: @PreetiMaurya Actually i have a scenario where i need this task. I need replica of DB

Comment: Create another table and store same value in that.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad i want to store in same table with same data

Comment: Ok then first select data from table and insert it into table again and user_id as primary auto increment so it can store data with new id.

Comment: @AmrutGaikwad u mean i create a new file which can get data from FORM and save it into db? M i right?

Comment: on click call ajax function and pass user_id so on php page you can select data & insert.

Comment: Ok I Will Try @AmrutGaikwad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82069/discussion-between-sunny-and-amrut-gaikwad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way. You can have multiple submit buttons. Like

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make a copy" />
```

When this forms get submitted, you can check which submit button was pressed by asserting with `$_POST['submit']` or `$_GET['submit']` if you method is `GET`.

For example:

```
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Make a copy') {
    $action = "copy";
} elseif($_POST['submit'] == 'Edit') {
    $action = "edit";
}
```

Using that you can know what the user wanted to do. Since you already have the data, just pass those to your function which creates a new record without the primary key.

Comment: Can u briefly explain it for me? Coz i am new in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to read rows with PHP and then insert them as new rows without specifying the ID column.

Another way it would be with SQL, doing an INSERT with SELECT query, but I have never done it. [You can check more info here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).